# Spring Boot MySQL Database Initialization Error with Stored Procedures

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot

In a Spring Boot application I am attempting to initialize some MySQL database tables and stored procedures before running integration tests by placing a schema.sql file in my resources directory as recommended in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html).

The create table statements work but the create procedure statements throw an exception. A sample schema.sql file statement that causes the exception is shown below:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `database`.FOO;
CREATE PROCEDURE `database`.FOO()

BEGIN
  SELECT * from `database`.employees;
END;
```

The issue is that the `;` character within the stored procedure is being parsed out by the Spring [ScriptUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.java) class that parses the schema.sql file before executing it, which then causes MySQL to throw a syntax error on the script.

I have looked at the [ScriptUtils](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/init/ScriptUtils.java) class and have not been able to find a way to escape the `;` characters with the procedures. Using `\\` and `\` as escape characters did not work either, as well as the MySQL `DELIMITER` command.

Has anyone been able to create MySQL stored procedures using the schema.sql file with Spring Boot? If so could they show an example?

For some additional information, the following [Spring JIRA issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13389) addresses the same topic but was closed with a *Won't Fix* label.

Comment: I don't have much info but may be try `^` as escape character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer turned out to be very simple. Spring Boot has a DataSource separator property that can be set in the application.properties file:

```
spring.datasource.separator=^;
```

Then in the schema.sql file all `;` statements not within the stored procedure need to be updated with the new separator.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `database`.FOO;
CREATE PROCEDURE `database`.FOO()

BEGIN
  SELECT * from `database`.employees;
END ^;
```

Comment: Don't miss the semicolon, in the separator (^;)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Andrews answer:

When using a custom `dataSource` that is not automatically created by Spring Boot, it can happen that the `spring.datasource.separator` property is not used. In this cases the separator is not forwarded to the `Populator`. In this case it can be set directly in the data source initialization. For example, the following can be used in a special update profile assuming `dataSource` is defined elsewhere:

```
<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" enabled="${initDatabase:false}" separator="^;">
    <jdbc:script location="${update.schema.script}" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Or, when the the populator is explicitly stated:

```
<bean id="dbPopulator" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator">
    <property name="separator" value="^;"/>
    <property name="scripts">
        <list>
            <value>${update.schema.script}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="initDatabase" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DataSourceInitializer">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource"/>
    </property>
    <property name="databasePopulator">
        <ref bean="dbPopulator"/>
    </property>
    <!-- The same can be done for the cleaner: -->
    <!-- <property name="databaseCleaner"><ref bean="dbCleanup"/></property> -->
</bean>
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone steps on this thread using spring-boot + testcontainers as I did, one can just omit separators, cause testcontainers' parser is [aware](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/issues/570) of procedures synthax (although still doesn't work for MS-SQL). So original script will work:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `database`.FOO;
CREATE PROCEDURE `database`.FOO()

BEGIN
  SELECT * from `database`.employees;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

If annotations are used for the test, then you can do the following:

```
@Sql(
        scripts = "/myTestSQL.sql",
        config = @SqlConfig(separator = "^;")
)
@Test
void mySQLTest() {
    // my test logic
}
```

given that `myTestSQL.sql` is stored in the test `resources` folder.
Also, only different procedures or queries are to be separated with `^;`, what's inside the procedure should still be separated with `;`, just like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/35871322/2092109 answer