# importing procedures through schema.sql spring boot

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot

I am importing procedures in postgres database on initializing spring boot app. I have refered few links below however none of the answer is working.

1.[spring-boot-mysql-database-initialization-error-with-stored-procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856652/spring-boot-mysql-database-initialization-error-with-stored-procedures)
2.[issue-with-executing-procedure-in-spring-boot-schema-sql-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32903696/issue-with-executing-procedure-in-spring-boot-schema-sql-file)

Here is my code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  sample(description varchar, name varchar)
  RETURNS integer LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
  DECLARE 
   BEGIN 
select * from "RESULT";
     return 1;
    end;
```

The error i am getting is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/D:/springDFA/DFA/target/classes/schema.sql]: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample(description VARCHAR, name varchar) RETURNS integer LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' DECLARE BEGIN select * from "RESULT"; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "DECLARE"
  Position: 105
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:769) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:218) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1341) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1187) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:392) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at com.dfa.application.SampleApplication.main(SampleApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
```

I have to create whole db structure on lunching spring boot app. I am just wandering is there any possibility to initialize backup script file (generated in postgres) in spring boot?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has invalid format, have a look at [CREATE FUNCTION](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-createfunction.html).
You could try this one:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sample(description varchar, name varchar)
RETURNS integer LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' AS ' DECLARE
  BEGIN
  select * from "RESULT";
  RETURN 1;
END; ';
```

Comment: special characters are not allowed while importing that's why i've removed it. Even if i add, its not working :( @i.bondarenko

Comment: I have just fixed the answer. Please try one more time.