# Is it possible to use $$ as a delimiter/separator in sql statement for postgrescontainer?

Tags: spring, postgresql, testing, integration-testing, testcontainers

We're using testcontainers in integration test with DB. To setup initial state of DB we use container method `withInitScript(*pathToScript*)`. Under the hood it uses `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement` class to execute query. But an executing fails if sqlQuery contains function/procedure with `$$` delimiter. The solution is to replace `$$` with `'`, but it takes long time to control sql sqript and keep in mind necessity of replacing  delimiter.

There is related question, but no solution: [Exception in JPA when using seed file for PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52228470/exception-in-jpa-when-using-seed-file-for-postgresql)

Is it possible to point a type of delimiter or something like that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856652/spring-boot-mysql-database-initialization-error-with-stored-procedures